# Rename image files on upload

Tags: php

I need help on renaming image files on upload using php. I wanted to rename my images with the userid of the user and a counter like userid-1.jpg, userid-2.jpg, userid-3.jpg and so on depending on the number of images uploaded by the user..
so far I have this code, and can't get this to work..

```
$id = $GET['id'];
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$upload_dir = '../uploads';

 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != null) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
        $tempfile= $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if ($tempfile != "") {
            $newFilePath = $upload_dir. $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($tempfile, $newFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Pls give me an idea on how to correct this..

Comment: Your file names are userid.jpg or user.jpg

Comment: It would be userid-1.jpg if user uploaded only one image.. then increment counter for the second filename if user uploads another image, so that would be like userid-2.jpg..

Comment: What happens if the user upload more files later? I assume that you would want the count to continue?

Comment: @Ryan Vincent yes correct, the count will continue if user uploads more files..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll want to use `intval()` on your `$_GET['id']`

Then edit your destination path in `move_uploaded_file` :

```
$id = intval($GET['id']);
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$upload_dir = '..'.$ds.'uploads'.$ds;

 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != null) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
        $tempfile= $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if ($tempfile != "") {
            $newFilePath = $upload_dir.'user_'.$id.'_'.time();
            move_uploaded_file($tempfile, $newFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Check the file type before moving it (so that people don't upload php files...) : http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

This way you can also determinate what the file extension has to be.

Also just to be sure, don't chmod 777 your uploads folder, it's much safer to simply give apache the ownership.

Comment: thank you for your input, I did try that but nothing is uploaded on the uploads folder, I'm trying to do renaming the files first then I'm gonna do some validation afterwards..

Comment: perhaps try setting the path absolutely.
For instance : `$upload_dir = $ds.'var'.$ds.'www'.$ds.'my_site'.$ds.'uploads'.$ds;`
Note that the upload folder must exist.

Answer (score 0):

`$newFilePath = $upload_dir. $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];` should be changed to watever name you want to give; as `$newFilePath = "".$upload_dir."/vikas.jpg";`